# ERROR ITMS-6000: "Not supported (relevant contracts not signed): has_hosted_content" at Software/SoftwareMetadata/SoftwareInAppPurchase

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

```
ERROR ITMS-6000: "Not supported (relevant contracts not signed): has_hosted_content" at Software/SoftwareMetadata/SoftwareInAppPurchase
```

i am having this problem in application loader in in-App purchase. unable to understand.

Comment: Maybe you did not accept changed contracts. Go to [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/). It show a warning including links in case there are contracts open for review.

Comment: could not understand. can you please elaborate it more..

Comment: Open the provided link and login. There might be a banner on the top stating something like "Some contracts have changed and need to be reviewed/ accepted by you". If so, accept them.

Answer (score 1):

There are contracts or licence agreements in Apple Member Center or iTunes Connect, which you have to accept.

- Open [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)
- Open "Aggreements, Tax & Banking" and log in
- Accept all required documents